# JQuery, Ajax and Internet Explorer - callback only works when response is blank

Tags: jquery

My code works perfectly in FF, Safari and Chrome... just in IE 7 and 8 this happens...

My JQuery AJAX post looks like this:

```
$.post( 'page.php', { test: 'testing' }, function(r){
    alert('Data: ' + r);
});
```

Now, in IE, if the response (r) comes back blank, it will display the alert. However, if there is anything returned in the r (even if it's just a digit such a 1), it doesn't show the alert. No errors come up, it just doesn't show the callback...

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Try `alert (r)`, without the prepended string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Internet Explorer" caches ajax-Request so first of all you should clear the cache of your browser and then edit your code to the following.

```
$.ajax({
      url: "page.php",
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      data: ({ test: 'testing' }),
      success: function(r){
          alert('Data: ' + r);
      }
   }
);
```

the use of **cache: false** forces the browser to not cache the result

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would try explicitly telling jQuery what type of data you expect back. If you expect plain text, say so like this:

```
$.post( 'page.php', { test: 'testing' }, function(r){
    alert('Data: ' + r);
}, 'text' );
```

If you expect a `JSON` response, provide that:

```
$.post( 'page.php', { test: 'testing' }, function(r){
    alert('Data: ' + r);
}, 'json' );
```

You can read more about the [acceptable types here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Why the Downvote? Is there something wrong with the answer? Would love the opportunity to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try 'ticking' your test data key?  Seems this happened to me once...

```
$.post( 'page.php', { 'test': 'testing' }, function(r){
    alert('Data: ' + r);
});
```